# Why does ByteBuffer.getFloat return 0.0?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

ByteBuffer byteBuffer is received over a TCP/IP connection, is visible in the NetBeans emulator, and contains 0x2b, 0x69, 0x80, and 0x3f in bytes 4, 5, 6, and 7 for this break.
If the endianess is wrong I would expect either an incorrect float value or possibly some type of numeric exception, but not always 0.0 for various sets of 4 bytes.
The same thing happens for a number of other floats read out of this ByteBuffer, at index 8, 12, etc. Why is the following always 0.0?

```
float f = byteBuffer.getFloat(4);
```

Comment: I suspect that the `ByteBuffer` doesn't contain what you think it does. Could you call `byteBuffer.get(i)` for `i=4,5,6,7` just before you call `getFloat(4)`, and print out the four values?

Comment: Damn! I'm doing a `ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(status.length)` and it is `status` that contains the data. I'm sure the `.allocate` probably just creates the byteBuffer and now I need to copy the byte[] status to the byteBuffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unable to reproduce:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytes = { 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1,  0x2b, 0x69, (byte) 0x80, 0x3f };
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        System.out.println(buffer.getFloat(4));
    }
}
```

As aix commented, I suspect your buffer doesn't really contain what you think it does.

What happens if you try it with `getInt(4)`?

Comment: Correct. It didn't. The original data is in a byte[] called `status` so I needed to do a `byteBuffer.put(status).`

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are not flipping your buffer after you read which means you are reading after the last thing written to.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
buffer.putFloat(1.2345f);
float f = buffer.getFloat(); // equals 0.0
System.out.println("before flip "+f);

buffer.flip();
float f2 = buffer.getFloat(); // equals 1.2345
System.out.println("after flip "+f2);
```

prints

```
before flip 0.0
after flip 1.2345
```

Comment: Should `ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4)?`

Comment: Not for this example. It would throw an exception if you did.

Comment: Yes. It did. That was odd. Does java need 8 bytes for floats?

Comment: You need 8 bytes if you are going to write 4 and then read 4.